# SQL find only records that appear more than once

Tags: sql

I am trying to select only the records that appear more than once.

Here is my table, I want to pull out records that have the same Column C.

```
A      B                C                   D
1 | 29-005628 | 100 TIMS CREEK RD        | WD66
2 | 29-005631 | 100 TIMS CREEK RD        | WT70
3 | 29-005635 | 5300 HIDDEN MANOR CT     | WT89
4 | 29-005638 | 600 LINDLEY CRESCENT AV  | WT30
5 | 29-005639 | 100 TIMS CREEK RD        | WT89
6 | 29-003238 | 501 PARK VIEW AV         | WT60
7 | 29-009104 | 501 PARK VIEW AV         | WT80
```

Desired Output:

```
A       B              C                     D
1 | 29-005628 | 100 TIMS CREEK RD        | WT66
2 | 29-005631 | 100 TIMS CREEK RD        | WT70
3 | 29-005639 | 100 TIMS CREEK RD        | WT89
4 | 29-003238 | 501 PARK VIEW AV         | WT60
5 | 29-009104 | 501 PARK VIEW AV         | WT80
```

Any help with a query would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select * from tablename 
where c in (select c from tablename group by c having count(c)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.c = t.c and t2.a <> t.a);
```